# Is it possible to replicate the net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error at the client-side when making an API call or using a WebSocket?

Tags: rest, sockets, server, elixir, client

I developed a live view application using Elixir, specifically a Phoenix application, and have been running it in the browser for an extended period of time. Occasionally, I encounter an error, such as net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET, which completely removes the socket connection and prevents automatic reconnection. It appears as though the server is unable to transmit data to the client. To address this issue, I implemented error protection logic in my application. However, I would like to test the end-to-end flow of this error, but I am having difficulty reproducing the net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error in my Chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

The `net:ERROR_CONNECTION_RESET` occurred due to a slow internet connection, which caused the `app.js` JavaScript file to fail to download properly. As a result, the live view phoenix app could not load and did not display the expected results.

To simulate the issue, I used a tool such as Fiddler or Wireshark to intercept or delay the connection. Specifically, I closed the network for `localhost:5000/js/app.js`, which prevented `app.js` from loading and triggered the aforementioned error.